# Keep screen off when proximity sensor is covered (in pocket)

Tags: proximity-sensor

I just recently switched to Sony XPERIA Z5, and I am quite annoyed with it doing things in my pocket. The phone is set to wake on double tapping (which is handy, for a user coming from nokia n9 and jolla). So the phone will randomly goes to the emergency dialer, attempting to unlock, or even may trigger the camera while it is in my pocket.

Since the phone has a proximity sensor built in, is it possible to make the phone aware of that when the screen is off? I mean I don't need it to be automatically switched off whenever it is covered. However, it would be nice if the screen doesn't turn on to load the lock screen when the proximity sensor is covered.

There should be a proper way of doing this right? If a jolla and nokia n9 can do it, I suppose it is going to be easy with Androids?

Comment: I've not tested this keeping your environmental conditions in mind, but [tag:Tasker] might be able to help you. It should be something like when display is on  -> lock screen and when proximity sensor reports near, turn screen off. Other automation apps from Play Store may also help here. //What Android version are you using? Is the Android rooted?

Comment: on 5.1.1 and it is not rooted, will prolly give tasker a try when i have time

Comment: Im inclined to say: nowadays, with AOSP having triggered so many actions unavailable to automation apps, it's a decision left to the user: either root the device, or stay uncomfortable. Sad thing, but that's it. I usually root my new devices *before* unboxing (i.e. easy-to-root is a major criterium in device selection for me). So I go with @Firelord – *Tasker* was my first idea as well.

Comment: lol, gotta wait a while to root my device if I don't want to lose the drm keys