# Screen turns "on" during calls- Samsung Galaxy A8

Tags: samsung, 5.1-lollipop, proximity-sensor

I have *Samsung Galaxy A8* and from yesterday my screen doesn't turn off during call and my ear keeps on touching other things in  display like hold calls ,mute etc,  giving me trouble .

What should I do ?

Comment: check call settings of device, and set proximity during call

Comment: Did you recently deploy a screen guard/protector/cover/glass?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your *Proximity Sensor* is not working as it should. See [Whats the use case of proximity sensor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44037/131553) . This could be due to software or hardware issue

- To check dial secret code **# 0 #**. See [Samsung Galaxy A8 Secret Codes, Hidden Menu in Samsung A8](http://www.samteck.net/2015/08/samsung-galaxy-a8-secret-codes-hidden.html?m=1). After reading the values follow steps [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2569141)
- Try fixing with apps like [Proximity Sensor Reset App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobiledirection.proximitysensorreset) or [Proximity Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vrognaas.proximityfix) which hasn't been updated since '14 but seems to work on some Samsung devices
- If that didn't help, try blowing hard into earphone jack (Proximity sensor in some devices is located close by and this may help release a "stuck" sensor)
- See [How to Perform Proximity Sensor Calibration on any Samsung Phone [Fix]](http://www.androidlegend.com/how-to-perform-proximity-sensor-calibration-on-any-samsung-phone/) for `adb` commands, which may work
- See [proximity-sensor](/questions/tagged/proximity-sensor) tag for other solutions that may work, if none above helped